# Export Excel column as CSV through VBA on MAC

Tags: excel, vba, macos, csv

MacBook Pro running Sonoma 14.1. Excel Version 16.81

Background: I work for a company that creates custom vehicles. I have a workbook that acts as a resource for the specifications of each build.

Sheet 1 contains a large table. The columns correspond with build aspects/qualities. The rows correspond with each individual build.

Sheet 2 has a selector that transposes a selected row by the build's corresponding stock number.

Sheet 2 then translates the technical information into "English", to be made sense by the end user.

Sheet 3 takes all of this information and puts it into a column.

I'm trying to make a VBA macro to export this column as a CSV, save it into a desktop folder, then use AppleScript/Automator to take the folder contents and use each CSV to populate a PDF.

I'm using this code now...

Sub ExportColumnToCSV()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Create")

Dim triggerCell As Range, dataRange As Range, filenameCell As Range
Set triggerCell = ws.Range("H4")
Set dataRange = ws.Range("D2:D51")
Set filenameCell = ws.Range("D2")

If triggerCell.Value = "on" Then
    Dim savePath As String
        savePath = "/Users/<USERNAME>/Documents"
    Dim csvFilename As String
        csvFilename = filenameCell.Value & ".csv"
    Dim csvPath As String
        csvPath = savePath & "/" & csvFilename
    
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(dataRange).Copy
    Dim csvFile As Workbook
    Set csvFile = Workbooks.Add
    
    csvFile.Sheets(1).Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    csvFile.SaveAs FileName = csvPath, FileFormat:=xlCSV
            
            triggerCell.Value = "OFF" ' Reset the trigger cell
End If
```

End Sub

My understanding is that this should:

1. set cell H4 as an on/off trigger
2. copy range d2:d51
3. Create a new sheet, named after the contents of D2
4. Save the new sheet as a CSV to the specified save path
5. Return the trigger cell to "Off"

I'm not sure why this isn't working. I have a very rudimentary level of VBA knowledge.

Let me know if more info is needed. Thanks!